# What is the name of a barcode that is just made of forward slashes and backslashes?

Tags: pdf, ocr, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I see barcodes in the margins of PDF documents that are made of only forward slashes and backslashes.  I believe this is a machine readable code that is added to some PDF documents to stipulate the coordinates that signatures, initials and dates are to be added.

An example looks like this:

```
\\\\\/////\/\\\/\////\/\
\\//\\\\\//\//\\///\///\
\\/\//\\\//\/\/\//\//\\/
/\\///\//\\/\\\\/\\\///\
/\//\////\/\\/\\//\\//\\
/\\/\\\\\\\/\///\\//\\\/
\/\//\\\\/\////\//\/\\//
/\//\//\////\//\//\\//\\
\//\/\\////\\/\////\\/\/
\\\//\//\/\\/\\\/\\\///\
\/\\/\//\/\\\\//\//\\\\\
\/\\\\\\/\\/\//\/\\\\/\/
/\/\\\//\/\////\\\//\\//
```

I found a real example in a court filing from a lawsuit online:

[image]
https://dms.psc.sc.gov/Attachments/Matter/162d6701-f451-49fc-9921-c7e5111c5395

I have not been able to find any descriptions of a similar barcode online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These barcodes seem to be "DataGlyphs". Wikimedia Commons has an [image of one such barcode](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dataglyph511140.png), which looks similar to the image in your question.

DataGlyphs appear to be a proprietary invention of Xerox PARC in about 1989. See their [history](https://www.parc.com/about-parc/parc-history/) page.